# android how to draw a bitmap on canvas semi transparent

Tags: android, bitmap, transparency

I have tried to modify a Paint variable, but have been unsuccessful - how can I make a bitmap appear "semi-transparent"?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);   
BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.loading);    
Bitmap bm = bd.getBitmap();    
Paint paint = new Paint();    
paint.setAlpha(60);                             //you can set your transparent value here    
canvas.drawBitmap(bm, 0, 0, paint);
```

Comment: Works perfect also in kotlin!

Answer (score 1):

```
Paint p = new Paint();
p.setAlpha(70);

Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.wallpaper);
canvas.drawBitmap(image, xPosition, yPosition, p);
```